# Linking attachments to Lead sent through Installed Package: LeadFromEmail

Tags: email2lead, emailfileattachment

I'm a total newbie to Apex and would really appreciate some help.

I am using the Installed Package: LeadFromEmail

In the settings I have enabled attachments to be processed, however attachments are not linking to the Lead and are 'vanishing'.

I have tried to look at the Apex Class installed as part of this package:

```
Name                EmailProcessor  Status              Active
Namespace Prefix    EZSAAS_E2L_W09  Installed Package   LeadFromEmail
```

However, I cannot edit it (I believe I need to?) as there is a satement on the screen:
This Apex Class is managed, meaning that you may only edit certain attributes

Can someone help?
I losing all attachments sent on emails that are being converted to Leads by this installed package!

Comment: [This app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cRqEAI)?

Answer (score 1):

In short, if an app is broken, we can't fix it, and you can't fix it. All you can do is try to contact the developer and see if they can push an update for you. This may involve checking debug logs, using login access, etc. Since the app is having its decennial birthday this year, there might not be much hope for it. You might want to start researching how to write something like this. It's only a single method, the [Messaging.InboundEmailHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm) interface. It wouldn't be too hard to write your own if you have any aptitude at all.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response - appreciate it. I am nowhere near a dev so I'll 'try' but just not sure how I go about it. If you (or anyone else) has any tips or can help it would be amazing!